# Adding limit to regexp constructor

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I limit this regexp to be applied to characters 0 to 15?:

```
function __highlight(s, t) {
  var xm = new RegExp("("+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t)+")", "ig" );
  return s.replace(xm, "<span style='color:red; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;'>$1</span>");
}
```

to match characters from 0 to 15?

tried `var matcher = new RegExp("("+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t)+")", "ig/^{0,15}*$/" );`

But its throwing an error.

The regexp is being called here:

```
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    //.append( "<a>" + "<img src='" + item.imgsrc + "' />" + item.id+ " - " + item.label+ "</a>" )
    // Appen d item.info from query to whow what column we have matched
    .append(__highlight(item.label + ' ' + item.info, this.term))
    .appendTo( ul );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var xm = new RegExp("("+$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(t)+"){0,15}", "ig" );
```

Comment: It does work but I am using this to format a string in an autocomplete jquery element. What is happening now is that the html element is converted to string. I have added to the question the call to the regexp function.

Comment: The answer was correct! It was my implementation that was wrong. I changed the __highlight() function to search only in item.label and it worked!